# Flutter : How to initialize DocumentSnapshot (must be initialize before use) in case of null safety

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

Recently, I started migrating the Flutter app with null safety, in the below code I do not know how to initialize DocumentSnapshot.

This code is used when a notification comes but to satisfy other flows the second argument should also be there, I can't remove the second argument.

1. if I use `late` with `DocumentSnapshot` then I get "The late local variable 'post' is definitely unassigned at this point." because I am passing the same value as the argument.
2. if I use `dynamic post;` then while passing the argument I am getting a null value.

this is the error I am getting:

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'

```dart
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage 
    message) {
      List<RemoteMessage> details = [];
    
      details.add(message);
    
      late DocumentSnapshot post;
    
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ViewDetailsPage(details: details, 
    post: post),
      ));
    });
```

This is the structure of ViewDetailsPage.dart

```dart
class ViewDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
    final DocumentSnapshot post;

    final List<RemoteMessage> details;

    ViewDetailsPage({Key? key, required this.details, required 
    this.post})
    : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ViewDetailsPageState(this.details, this.post);
    }
}
```

There are two arguments in `ViewDetailsPage(details: details, post: post)`

details ---> is the data that is being sent by FCM

if "details" has some data then "post" does not have any data.
if "post" has some data then "details" does not have any data.

post ---> is the data that is being displayed by the recyclerView

Comment: Include the full code.
Can't really understand why you have to do that in that way.

Comment: here is details

Comment: cant see where you've assign the `post`

Comment: Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => ViewDetailsPage(details: details, 
post: post)

Comment: This code doesn't make sense.  Why are you declaring an uninitialized `post` variable inside of a callback declaration and then trying to pass it as an argument?  Where is its initial value supposed to come from?  What was the code before you tried migrating from null-safety?

Comment: @jamesdlin exactly what I wanted to say...

Comment: You still haven't explained exactly where you expect `post` to be initialized for any scenario. *Where* do you expect to get an actual `DocumentSnapshot` object?  How did any of this code work before you attempted to migrate to null-safety?

Comment: there is no use of "post" in the current scenario but in another scenario I am passing documentSnapshot. I have to forcefully pass the "post" because of the constructor structure.

The constructor structure is already given in question

Comment: In general, code of the form `T x;` before null-safety would be now equivalent to `T? x;`.  If you're in doubt, just make your variables nullable and check whether they're `null` before dereferencing them.  If you're *forced* to pass `post` to `ViewDetailsPage` but don't actually have a value to pass, then perhaps you should fix your code so that you aren't required to pass a non-`null` value.

Comment: thank God you understood the question
I have to pass the "post" forcefully but I can't change the constructor structure because in other scenarios I am passing and using values of documentSnapshot

Comment: I don't understand.  Why can't you simply make the `ViewDetialsPage` use a `DocumentSnapshot?` member instead?  Making it nullable would not prevent other callers from passing non-`null` values. That is how your code would have worked before null-safety. (Once again: **what did your code look like before you tried to migrate it?**)

Comment: class ViewDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot post;

  List<RemoteMessage> details;

  ViewDetailsPage({Key key, @required this.details, this.post})
      : super(key: key);

  override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ ViewDetailsPageState(this.details, this.post);
  }
}

Comment: FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage message) {
      //If there is data in our notification
      if (message != null) {
        List<RemoteMessage> details = [];

        details.add(message);

        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ViewDetailsPage(details: details),
        ));
      }

Comment: Earlier @required was not applicable for "post" in the constructor. Now I have to pass forcefully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251638/discussion-between-jamesdlin-and-amit-chaudhary).

Comment: @Amitchaudhary As I tried to explain in the chat, my suggestion is *not* about using `final`, it's about declaring your variable as *nullable* (`DocumentSnapshot?` instead of `DocumentSnapshot`).  That will allow it to be `null` by default and not be `required`.